# When are local static objects created?

Tags: c++

Chapter 6.1.1 of the book C++ Primer says the following:

> Each local `static` object is initialized before the first time execution passes through the object’s definition. Local statics are not destroyed when a function ends; they are destroyed when the program terminates.

To check this, I ran the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

using std::clog;
using std::endl;

struct Bar {
    Bar() {
        clog << "constructing Num object" << endl;
    }

    int i = 0,
        j = 0;

    ~Bar() {
        clog << "destructing Num object" << endl;
    }
};

void foo() {
    clog << "foo() started" << endl;
    static Bar b;
    return;
}

int main() {
    if (true) {
        clog << "if-statement started" << endl;
        foo();
    }

    clog << "if-statement exited" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

At this point in the book I haven't covered `struct`s and `class`es yet, but it is my understanding that the function `Bar()` logs a message to the standard output when it gets created, and that `b` gets default initialized. If that is the case, then why does the output show that the object is constructed / initialized when control reaches `static Bar b;`, and not *before* it reaches this statement?

Output:

```
if-statement started
foo() started
constructing Num object
if-statement exited
destructing Num object
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> When are local static objects created?

As your book says: "before the first time execution passes through the object’s definition".

More precisely, the standard's wording is:

> Dynamic initialization of a block-scope variable with static storage duration or thread storage duration is performed the first time control passes through its declaration; such a variable is considered initialized upon the completion of its initialization.

I think you're getting too hung up on the word "before".

Comment: the usage of "before" is indeed confusing. The object is not initialized **before** the definition, at least there would be no way to observe such "before"

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, the word _before_ threw me off indeed. Makes me wonder why they even used that word, would be clearer if they omitted that.

Comment: @idclev463035818 _"at least there would be no way to observe such 'before'"_ Exactly. Immediately before, during, immediately after, what's the difference? None.